# Preventing non-logged in members from accessing a certain page

Tags: asp.net, security

I'm using ASP.net and the only 'member' to the site will be me, with site-admin privileges.  I'm setting it up so I can make small edits to pages without having to re-upload the site every time.

I have an "editpage.aspx" page that I'm going to have it send me to-to edit the page.  How do I keep other nosy people from accessing the page without being logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this. On my sites, where I have the only login (i.e. there is no need for a full-blow membership provider as everyone but the admin runs not logged in), after I login, I set a flag in a session variable. On each page that I need to protect I do this in the page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["myUser"] == null)
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
```

That way, anyone that arrives on your page that is not logged in, gets redirected to the login page. This is a pretty simple solution, and easy to implement. But I wouldn't hide state secrets behind it...but have never had a problem with unauthorized users getting into protected pages.

Using a session has the benefit of timing out so that if a logged in user walks away from his computer, after 20 minutes or so the session expires and they are no longer logged.

Comment: "After I login I set a session variable." Could you elaborate? Where do you land when you login and how do you know you are logged in when you land there?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, [Basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) will most likely be enough.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. So, when people want to edit a page, the script sends you an email? That means you already have an authentication system, right?

Comment: no no no no... I have no clue where you got that idea (Mr ROBLOX fan =P).  I have a normal log-in system.  I don't want them to have to log-in again!

Comment: Yes, but in the first sentence of your question you said the only member of the site will be you. So, you want to be able to edit the page without having to login again?

Comment: I log in, I go to edit the page.  I don't need to type in a USR/PAS every time I go to edit a page.

Comment: So, only you should be able to log in?